# Less conditional style inclusion

Tags: css, less, conditional-statements, stylesheet

I'm kinda new to LESS, so I'm not sure if that's possible and how.
So my idea is this :

I have a main-stylesheet.less and a dozen smaller stylesheets each of which contains several versions of styling for a particular element i.e. header.less, footer.less, main-nav.less etc.
So in header.less every variant of styling is linked to a condition and when you include this LESS file in the main-stylesheet.less via this condition, just that particular chunk of code is compiled and not the other ones that are linked to other conditions.

I hope I've been thorough enough for you to best understand me.

Is this possible and how ?

Comment: Could you post the 'condition' you are using and header.less code?

Comment: Currently, I don't have any conditions, cause I'm not sure how to do this thing.
the CSS looks like that at the moment http://jsfiddle.net/yJLnt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Keeping it Generic

By using conditional mixins, the code in `main-stylesheet.less` stays generic, with only the variables changing to control what is actually compiled.

**Example header.less**

```
.header() when (@header = 1) {
   #header {
     your: properties;
     for: header1;
   }
}

.header() when (@header = 2) {
   #header {
     your: properties;
     for: header2;
   }
}
```

This could continue on, and similar code would be in the other `footer.less` files, etc.

**Example main-sytlesheet.less**

```
@import header.less;
@import main-nav.less;
@import footer.less;

/* set your variables for your conditional mixins */
@header: 1;
@main-nav: 3;
@footer: 3;

/* call the mixins */
.header();
.main-nav();
.footer();
```

The global variables you set will only choose the `.header()` mixin to generate the `#header`, etc. that `@header` variable is set to.

Comment: @ScottS Ah, sorry - I've missed it was cut. Never mind though - I think I change my mind and do not want to bother the OP with additional details (obviously I was about to mention "only one such global scope condition per a project" kind of stuff)...

Answer (score 3):

I think maybe your looking for a [**LESS mixin**](http://lesscss.org/)?

```
/* header.less  */

.header1 () {
    // including selector
    .header {
        position: relative; 
        z-index: 1001; 
        width: 100%; 
        margin: 0 0 20px; 
        overflow: hidden; 
    }
}
.header2 () {
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 1001; 
    width: 50%; 
    margin: 20px;  
}
.header3 () {
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 1; 
    width: 90%; 
    margin: 0 0 50px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

And include it like this:

```
/* main-stylesheet.less  */

@import 'header.less';

body {
   .header1();
}
```

You could also get smart and use one mixin:

```
.header (@margin: 0, @width: 100%) {
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 1001; 
    width: @width; 
    margin: @margin; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
header {
    .header(0 0 20px, 50%);
}
```

Comment: May be I wasn't clear enough, sorry about that, but I actually want to add not just the styles for the ".header" element. I want to include the whole selector with the styles within it :) How might that be achieved ?

Comment: You should just have to wrap the CSS with the desired selector. I've updated the first HTML section in my answer.